# How to use fmincon to optimize two control vectors of a function

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a function of 2 different vector. These are the control vector (decision variables) of the function. I want to use `fmincon` to optimize this function and also get the both control vector results separately.
I have tried to use handle ,@, but I got an error.
The function is:

```
function f = myFS(x,sv)      % x is a vector (5,1)
    f = norm(x)^2-sigma*(sv(1)+sv(2));
end
```

%% I tried to write `fmincone` to consider both control vectors (x and sv)

```
  [Xtemp(:,h2),Fval, fiasco] = fmincon(@(x,sv)myFS(x,sv)...
,xstart,[],[],[],[],VLB,VUB,@(x,sv)myCon(sv),options);
```

Here is the error I get:

> Error using myFS (line 12) Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in fmincon (line 564)
>         initVals.f =
>         feval(funfcn{3},X,varargin{:});
>
> Error in main_Econstraint (line 58) [Xtemp(:,h2),Fval, fiasco] =
>   fmincon('myFS',xstart,[],[],[],[],VLB,VUB,@(x,sv)myCon(sv),options);

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fmincon expects your function to be of a single variable, there is no getting around that, but see:

http://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html

for example, if both x, cv are variables of the optimization you can combine them and then split them in the actual objective

for example

`x_cv = vertcat(x, cv)` and then `x = x_cv(1:5); cv  = x_cv(6:end)`'

if cv is not a variable of the optimization, then 'freeze it' as the link above suggests